# Magento multiversion module Error class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option not found

Tags: magento-1.5, magento-1.7

I'm trying to create module for magento. It use my own class

```
class Myfirm_Extname_Model_Mysql4_Product_Option extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option
```

In magento 1.7 all works fine, in 1.5  - `error: Error class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option not found.`

How can I make class that will be inherited from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option` or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Option` depending on the version of magento?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this prodblem.

```
protected function _getResource() {
       if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<')) {
            $this->_resourceName = $this->_resourceName.'_oldversion';
        }
        if (empty($this->_resourceName)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Resource is not set.'));
        }

        return Mage::getResourceSingleton($this->_resourceName);
    }
```

And then create 2 resource model class for old version of magento and new